# Find key of a multi-dimensional associative array by value in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find the key of a multi-dimensional array using array functions (without looping the entire array set).

My array is like below,

```
$main_array = [];

$main_array[0]['id']=1001;
$main_array[0]['name']=test1;
$main_array[1]['id']=1002;
$main_array[1]['name']=test2;
$main_array[2]['id']=1001;
$main_array[2]['name']=test3;
```

I want to get the index of array by using the value without looping all the array (because my array is bit huge).

If I pass the value "1001", I want the two index 0 and 2. Tried with `array_search()` function, not working in my case.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: If you want all the keys that contain a given value, you're going to have to loop over the entire array. The only difference is that `array_search` doesn't require you to write the actual loop. But the data is still being iterated over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider changing structure of `array`. As your ID is not unique, elements with same ID stay in one `array`.

```
$main_array = array(
    1001 => array(
        array('name' => 'test1'),
        array('name' => 'test3'),
    ),
    1002 => array(
        array('name' => 'test2'),
    )
);
```

So

```
print_r( $main_array[1001] );
```

would give you

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => test1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test3
        )

)
```

If this is not possible, you have to loop over the entire array to achieve this.

```
function arraySearchId( $id, $array ) {
    $results = array();
    foreach ( $array as $key => $val ) {
        if ( $val['id'] === $id ) {
            $results[] = $key;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r( arraySearchId( 1001, $main_array ) );
echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
)
```

Comment: he asked without looping the array.

Comment: I understand that, I'm saying that he should consider changing structure of array. If he dosen't want to do that, he could still use this function.

Comment: I have to change the structure or else have to loop it. No other options.. Thanks @rene

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you could avoid completely from searching the array.

your structure is not planned well. you should have used the id (which should be unique) as keys for your array like so:

```
$main_array[1001]['name'] = 'foo'
```

this would be much easier to handle and to maintain.

I suggest you to make an effort and change your structure before it gets really big.

Comment: no. I cant.. this is key is not unique.. more than one element having the same 1001. check my array

Comment: then you should provide your own unique id for each set. this is basic planning. you'll need somehow to find your records, that's the reason tables in SQL are encouraged to use unique primary keys. that being said, In your case, if you wont change your structure, I dont see how you'll be able to find that key without foreaching the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

As your code

```
$main_array = [];
$main_array[0]['id']=1001;
$main_array[0]['name']=test1;
$main_array[1]['id']=1002;
$main_array[1]['name']=test2;
$main_array[2]['id']=1001;
$main_array[2]['name']=test3;
```

You require "Without looping", and the answer is: You must loop it at least once, to pre-process the data, make an indexed array.

```
$indexed = array();
foreach($main_array as $i=>$item) {
    if( !isset($indexed[$item['id']]) ) $indexed[$item['id']] = array();
    $indexed[$item['id']][] = $i;
}
```

When you need to find 1001, just

```
$result = $indexed['1001'] // array(0,2)
```

Comment: this is looping. he specifically asked without looping.

Comment: If want to make without looping, only way is change the array structure, just like the answer by Rene Korss